# For a commutative ring $R$, why does $1-ab$ being a non-unit leads to $1-ab \in M$ for some maximal ideal $M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Suppose there is a commutative ring $R$, without any restriction. Now suppose $a,b \in R$. If $1-ab$ is a non-unit, why is there at least one maximal ideal $M$ that $1-ab \in M$?

Comment: Yes. Consider the ideal $\left < 1-xy \right>.$ It's a proper ideal and hence contained in a maximal ideal.

Answer (score 4):

If an element is not a unit, the ideal it generates is not all of $R$. Now, every proper ideal is contained in a maximal ideal.